# How to restrict a Google Cloud function to be invoked only from the Google Cloud Console?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase function to do some data processing, and I only want to invoke it through Google Cloud Console manually.

Just a simple function like this (using node.js):

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'

// // Start writing Firebase Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript
//
export const test = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  res.send({
    query: req.query,
    body: req.body,
  })
})
```

The way I did it is to deploy the function via the firebase-cli then remove the `Cloud Function Invoker` role in the permission tab from GUI.

It seems to work.

But I noticed one thing, when I send the request with **Postman**

**when you send a `GET`, the error is 400,**
[image]

**But for any request that's not a `GET`, you get a proper `403`**
[image]

**My questions are:**

1. why `GET` is 400 while the others are 403?
2. am i doing it right in terms of my requirement?
3. what's the correct way of doing it?
4. does the function get invoked while sending a request like `POST`?

Comment: Please edit the question to show how exactly you are making the requests so that anyone can reproduce the behavior what you are observing without having to guess.  You might even want to show a [complete minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) function code that we could use as well.

Comment: Also I will say that rejecting invocations anywhere but the console is likely not a supported use case for Cloud Functions.  Functions are meant to be invoked by way of cloud product events or direct requests from HTTP clients.  I doubt you'll find anything in the documentation supporting what you want to do.

Comment: @DougStevenson wow, the official team member is answering questions on SO, impressed! Thanks, updated with code and I send via Postman. I tried it now, GET is returning 403, maybe a cache issue previously... so only 1 question, will it get billed if 403? understood not a normal requirement, just want to make sure i am doing it in a secure way. :)

Comment: @AlbertGao Google Cloud Functions offer free tier. It provides 400,000 GB-seconds, 200,000 GHz-seconds of compute time and 5GB of Internet egress traffic per month. On top of that, first 2 million invocations is also free. You may check this link on [Cloud Function pricing](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing).